# Single-EXE GUI client to download files from web server?

Tags: windows, http, gui

I uploaded a bunch of files on a web server that a friend of mine would like to download.

Problem is, he has very little computer knowledge, so I'd like to make things as easy as possible.

I know about VisualWGet, but it requires running an installer, and then adding files manually to the list of files to download (Jobs > New Multiple).

Ideally, I'd like a Windows, single-EXE client that can grab all files from a directory (the server allows directory listing) or takes a list of files as input (e.g., www.acme.com/files.txt)

Does someone know of something that would fit the bill?

Answer (score 2):

How about [wGetGUI](http://www.jensroesner.de/wgetgui/)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short idea fixed with [Windows wget](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/)

- write a BATCH script to issue `wget.exe` with the list of files to be downloaded
- package these 3 things into a ZIP and send it to him

  - wget.exe
  - BATCH file
  - list of download links

Should try once locally if you do not want him debugging.

---

If you have a nice fat upload path, you can host the files straight from your machine.
Use the [Opera Unite](http://unite.opera.com/) to setup the file server on your machine.
Start it, test it, get over phone and see the transfer complete (maybe), stop it.

Comment: +1 I would not bother with a list of download links. I'd just put everything in the batchfile.

Comment: @Ludwig, `wget -i` handles a list very nicely, better than writing an invocation for every file in the batch script.

Answer (score 1):

To make it easy on him, you could zip up all the files you want to give him, put the zip in an accessible (but passworded if necessary) spot on your web server (or use something like skydrive) and give him the web address.  That way, all he needs is a browser.

Comment: Thanks guys. I forgot to say that the files > 2GB, and when zipping them in TotalCommander, it said that ZIP files that big would not be readable. I don't know if it's a limitation of the ZIP format itself, or just the zipper that's included in TC.

As for wget, it won't do. He has no idea what a DOS box is, and, if possible, I'd like to avoid having him run an installer.

wGetGui below requires wget, the UI is very busy, and it failed starting because of an ActiveX control (error 429) :-/

Answer (score 1):

[DownloadThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201) for firefox?

> DownThemAll is fast, reliable and easy-to-use! It lets you download all the links or images contained in a webpage and much more: you can refine your downloads by fully customizable criteria to get only what you really want!

Answer (score 0):

wget.exe

@http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/
 **EDIT**: Didn't see the gui part in the question. I like the wgetgui above! Sorry!

Comment: What about just pointing his browser to the directory and letting him click the links? I know you don't want to use wget, but you could do it easily with one command:  wget -mrnp http://... that will recursivly download everything. Just point it to the top level directory you want to start in. If you don't want to download everything, you could just put links to all the files in a txt file and do wget -i nameoftxtfilewithlinks